# How can I add multiple tooltips on kendo ui grid.

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to have different tooltips in different columns on a kendo ui grid. 
I am examine the example 
http://dojo.telerik.com/@pfilipov/iGetO/2
but I can't find the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you require Angular syntax as in example? - I don't speak Angular, but here is basic solution where I do not need to.

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ohAje)

Also there is *content* function where you can catch and react according to attributes - in that case Title. So if you need calculate some equation (for example) you can create condition *if(title == Tooltip1)* and do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
$("#Kendo-grid-div-id").kendoTooltip({
    filter: "td:nth-child(2),td:nth-child(3)", //comma separated multiple columns
    position: "bottom",     //possible values: bottom,top,left,right,center
    content: function(e){
      var content = e.target.html();
      return content;
    }
  }).data("kendoTooltip");
```

This works for me!!!