# Kendo grid How can I display row content on mouse over for each column as my data is huge?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to display open a pane where I can display the full text of selected column.
I was referring to
[How can I add multiple tooltips on kendo ui grid.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403108/how-can-i-add-multiple-tooltips-on-kendo-ui-grid#)

but not getting how to get the tooltip for each column selected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See if [this demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bYP8HdsAFjm8BtAYktQP?p=preview) helps you.

The Tooltip widget has a `content` configuration that accepts either a string or a function returning a string.
This function gets a parameter containing the target for the tooltip which is the element your mouse is hovering over.

You can filter the elements so that only `td`s pop the tooltip.

Here's how I built and applied the tooltip options object I use in the example:

```
$("#container").kendoTooltip({
    filter: "td",
    content: function(e) {return e.target.html();}
});
```

This example will show a tooltip containing the same content as the cell you're poining at.

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask them.

Comment: Hey Shai, Thanks for the response. I need to hide the text in the row and display the full text on mouse over.

Comment: You mean that the table itself will be empty and the contents will be visible only in the tooltip?

Comment: I need to hide the text to avoid multi lines in a row

Comment: You can prevent multiple lines in a row by disabling word-wrap

Comment: Take a look at the demo again, I made some adjustments

Comment: This helped me thanks for the help. I appreciate a lot.

Comment: If the answer suited you, please accept it so that others in the future will see it's solved

Comment: Done Thanks Shai.